# Frequency Table Generation - MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I need to generate a simple frequency table in MongoDB. Let's say I have the following documents in a collection called `books`.

```
{
  "_id": 1,
  genre: [
    "Fantasy",
    "Crime",
    "Drama"
  ]
}
{
  "_id": 2,
  genre: [
    "Drama"
  ]
}
```

The expected output is:
Fantasy: 1
Crime: 1
Drama: 2

Assuming that I don't have a preformed notion of what genres are possible, how can I get MongoDB to detect the genres and count them? This seems like a job for the aggregation framework.

So far, I've gotten to this stage:

```
db.books.aggregate([
  {
      $group: {
        _id: null,
        test: {$push: "$genre"}
      }
  } 
])
```

This does not work as intended, as it just adds the genre array from each document. Can anyone point me in the right direction? Should I be using the aggregation framework?

Thank you!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When dealing with arrays in the aggregation framework what you generally need to do is use [**`$unwind`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/). This processes the array and essentially produces a new document for each array member. Think of it as "de-normalizing" with a SQL JOIN.

Once the array is "unwound" then you can process your [**`$group`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/):

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
    { "$unwind": "$genre" },
    { "$group": {
        "_id": "$genre",
        "count": { "$sum": 1 }
    }}
])
```

This gives output like:

```js
{ "_id" : "Drama", "count" : 2 }
{ "_id" : "Crime", "count" : 1 }
{ "_id" : "Fantasy", "count" : 1 }
```

The `_id` provided to `$group` is the "key" that you want to group on, in your case this is "genre" referred to as it's "value" by prefixing with the `$` "$genre". The [**`$sum`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sum/) simply adds up values of 1 for each occurrence, which is generally how you count.

There are several examples shown at the [SQL to Aggregation mapping chart](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/sql-aggregation-comparison/), which is not only a useful guide for those used to SQL but had general practical examples of usage as well.

Comment: Thanks for pushing me in the right direction. $unwind got me on the right path, and the examples you showed are quite useful. Others take note. I had to revise your answer to get the desired results (the shell didn't seem to like the "" for the leading key value pairs. For example "$unwind" was $unwind).

Comment: @DiodeDan The shell has no problem with the syntax as shown and this along with just about everything I post is a complete cut/paste from working code. I think you will find you actually made an error in your transcription. The shell does not require the quoting but this is the valid JSON format representation. I post this way so others can pick up the JSON and just parse it into native data structures for their own language.